# best method to update a table from a materialized view log

Tags: oracle, etl, materialized-views

Imagine I have an oracle database with data that is constantly changing, a strategy to capture changes on this db is to work with materialized view and materialized view log.

Let's consider table `T` as an example:

```
describe T
 Name                                         Null?    Type
 -------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------
 KEY                                          NOT NULL NUMBER
 VAL                                                   VARCHAR2(5)
```

Let's create a `mv` for table `t` with fast refresh:

```
create materialized view mv
  REFRESH FAST
  as select * from t
;
```

View the content of the `mv`:

```
select key, val, rowid
from   mv ;

      KEY VAL   ROWID
---------- ----- ------------------
         1 a     AAAWm+AAEAAAAaMAAA
         2 b     AAAWm+AAEAAAAaMAAB
         3 c     AAAWm+AAEAAAAaMAAC
         4       AAAWm+AAEAAAAaMAAD
```

Now I create a `mv` log to track changes on the base table:

```
create materialized view log on t ;

describe MLOG$_T
 Name                                         Null?    Type
 -------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------
 KEY                                                   NUMBER
 SNAPTIME$$                                            DATE
 DMLTYPE$$                                             VARCHAR2(1)
 OLD_NEW$$                                             VARCHAR2(1)
 CHANGE_VECTOR$$                                       RAW(255)
```

At this point the the mv log is empty because no change has been applied:

```
select * from MLOG$_T ;

no rows selected
```

Let's apply changes:

```
UPDATE t set val = upper( val ) where KEY = 1 ;

INSERT into t ( KEY, val ) values ( 5, 'e' );

select key, dmltype$$ from MLOG$_T ;

       KEY DMLTYPE$$
---------- ----------
         1 U
         5 I
```

An update and insert has been recorded as we can see above. If we refresh the mv the changes will be applied to the mv, and the log will be deleted.

Now let's imagine I have another table `t2` that is the same table as mv and `t` before changes have been applied to `t`. How can I update `t2` only from reading the logs of the `mv log` ? I ask this because in reality `t2` will be a table in another database (staging server) which I will updating and applying some ETL as the changes in the mv log happen. Therefore applying the changes in `t2` the materialized view log is crucial. I'm also open to new strategies because I believe this causes the oracle databse some overhead.

Comment: Make `t2` an MV and refresh from `t` over a database link. Then MV Log management is automatic. If `t` handles a lot of transactions then fast refresh your MVs frequently. This keeps the size of the MV Log down and the relative size of the refresh transactions small (i.e. less impact on your overall performance profile; no spikes).

Comment: but I want `t2` to be something like a fact table in the data warehouse. Can I construct relationships with other tables being `t2` a MV ? not sure it's good design to build a data warehouse on MVs

Comment: Data warehouses are often built on and of MVs, which are in fact, just tables. You can't use MV Logs for any other purpose.

Comment: Yeah but what if I don't want `t2` to refresh on dml operations such as delete but only insert and update? I would need to apply the log changes only for those cases right?  and not delete

Comment: You won't have any way to sync with the log, especially if it is being used by an actual MV. It can't really double as a change data capture for other purposes. You'd need to have an MV in the warehouse to capture the raw data, then use a trigger on the MV to only process the inserts and updates into the actual fact table. This too - importing raw data and the curating it for reporting purposes - is common in data warehouses.

Comment: Or use a `MERGE` DML statement in a stored procedure in the DW to capture differences between `t` and `t2` - that would be less efficient (more data scanned and changed with each refresh) but might also work.